# Algorithm which add itself

Tags: c, algorithm

What line of codes would work to make the following derivation(with the exact order):

```
int y[i][j];

y[0][0]=0

y[1][0]=0+4

y[2][0]=0+16
y[2][1]=0+4+16

y[3][0]=0+64
y[3][1]=0+4+64
y[3][2]=0+16+64
y[3][3]=0+4+16+64

y[4][0]=0+256
y[4][1]=0+4+256
y[4][2]=0+16+256
y[4][3]=0+4+16+256
y[4][4]=0+64+256
y[4][5]=0+4+64+256
y[4][6]=0+16+64+256
y[4][7]=0+4+16+64+256

...
..
.
```

See the pattern? it keep adding itself for every increase in 'i'.

Comment: i figured that all of it is at power of 4, put in while loop and adding itself.., but i cant figure out an algorithm that can add itself at that same exact order.

Comment: Hint - `y[3][0] = y[2][0]-16+64`, `y[3][1] = y[2][1]-16+64`, `y[3][2] = y[2][0]+64`, `y[3][3] = y[2][1]+64`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  int z[16], y[5][8];

  int p = 1;
  z[0] = 0;
  y[0][0] = 0;
  for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++){
    for (int n = 0; n < p; n++){
      z[p+n] = p*p + z[n];
      y[k+1][n] = 4*z[p+n];
    }
    p += p;
  }
```

[codepad](http://codepad.org/aK4x6qwJ)